# Why is $\langle j^\mu j^\nu \rangle$ the vacuum polarization amplitude?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics

In QED, we often call the diagram:
[image]

the one-loop "vacuum polarization diagram" and we say that it is given by:
$$\Pi^{\mu\nu}(q)=\int\!d^4x e^{iq\cdot x} \langle T\{j^\mu(x) j^\nu(0)\} \rangle\;.$$
But looking at the diagram, I would have thought that what we really need to define is
$$\frac{i}{q^2+i\epsilon}\Pi^{\mu\nu}(q)\frac{i}{q^2+i\epsilon} = \int\!d^4x e^{iq\cdot x} \langle T\{A^\mu(x) A^\nu(0) \}\rangle\;,$$
at one loop. Are these definitions equivalent? I'm having trouble seeing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full non-perturbative proof of this fact proceeds as follows:

1. Use the LSZ reduction formula to convert the $\langle AA\rangle$ correlator into the following scattering amplitude $\leftrightarrow$ S-matrix element:
   $$
   \langle f|i\rangle=\epsilon_\mu^{(1)}\epsilon_\alpha^{(2)}i^n \int\mathrm d^4x_1e^{ip_1x_1}\partial^2_{(1)}g^{\mu\nu}\int\mathrm d^4x_2e^{ip_2x_2}\partial^2_{(2)}g^{\alpha\beta}\langle A_\nu(x_1)...A_\beta(x_2)...\rangle\tag{1}
   $$
2. Use the classical EOM for the photon field
   $$
   \frac{\delta\mathcal L}{\delta A^\mu}~=~-\partial^2A_\mu~=~j_\mu,\qquad j^\mu~=~\bar\psi\gamma^\mu\psi\tag{2}
   $$
   in the [Schwinger-Dyson equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger%E2%80%93Dyson_equation)
   $$
   \left\langle\frac{\delta S}{\delta\phi_j}\phi_1...\phi_n\right\rangle=i\sum_{k=1}^n\left\langle\phi_1...\delta_{jk}...\phi_n\right\rangle\tag{3}
   $$
   to replace the photon fields in the correlator with currents:
   $$
   \partial^2_{(1)}g^{\mu\nu}\ \partial^2_{(2)}g^{\alpha\beta}\langle A_\nu(x_1)...A_\beta(x_2)...\rangle=\langle j^\mu(x_1)...j^\alpha(x_2)...\rangle+\underbrace{\partial^2_{(2)}g^{\mu\alpha}\partial^2_{(1)}\Delta(x_1-x_2)\langle...\rangle+...}_\text{contact terms}\tag{4A}
   $$
   The reason we cannot directly substitute the classical relations $(2)$ into $(1)$ is because they are, well, classical. Equation $(3)$ says that the classical EOM hold inside correlation functions only up to *contact terms* on the RHS.
3. The contact terms do not contribute to the S-matrix as they yield disconnected diagrams, i.e. contractions between external photons. Alternatively, they do not have the correct pole structure in momentum space. Consequently we have as a special case:
   $$
   \partial^2_{(1)}g^{\mu\nu}\ \partial^2_{(2)}g^{\alpha\beta}\langle A_\nu(x_1)A_\beta(x_2)\rangle=\langle j^\mu(x_1)j^\alpha(x_2)\rangle\tag{4B}
   $$
   at the level of S-matrix elements. Substituing this result into the initial scattering amplitude, we see that **all amputated photons in S-matrix elements can be replaced with currents, within correlation functions**. (As it turns out, this statement holds when external momenta are not on-shell).

<sup>(Conventions: Feynman-'t Hooft gauge; renormalisation parameters elided; deWitt condensed notation)</sup>

Comment: Nice answer! I'm still digesting it. Two questions: 1) You are using $Z_3=Z_1$? and 2) Did you actually make use of the LSZ formula?

Comment: @EricDavidKramer 1. No, but I have removed the references to renormalisation since it's not very useful to the discussion, 2. Yes, to rewrite the AA correlator as a scattering amplitude

Comment: But since your final equation (which is what I was looking for) does refer to the scattering amplitude, it seems like the scattering amplitude just came along for the ride. Is there any way of bypassing it?

Comment: @EricDavidKramer I'm not sure what you mean. We can only drop the contact terms if we are working with scattering amplitudes, otherwise they remain.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm starting to understand. What do you mean by "in S-matrix elements" and "within correlation functions". These sound like two different things.

Comment: @EricDavidKramer 1. "in S-matrix elements" = when you are computing scattering amplitudes/S-matrix elements; 2. "within correlation functions" = the photon fields are inside the correlation functions and are replaced by currents. The photon field is inside a correlation function which is in the LSZ reduction formula.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm just trying to decide which answer here is the best. Prahar only gave an answer in perturbation theory, but his answer seems to not require S-matrix elements. Do you agree?

Comment: @EricDavidKramer 1. Prahar's version _does_ require the LSZ reduction formula at the end, to get rid of his photon propagators in order to prove that the amplitudes are the same. 2. Mine is non-perturbative while Prahar's is perturbative (and I am not so sure the generalisation is so straaightforward). Interesting fact - I believe all three of us, coincidentally, attended the Strings 2021 conference.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right (about LSZ and strings)! Anyway, thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 5):

The difference between the two diagrams is with whether you include the photon propagators in your calculation. For instance, consider the Lagrangian
$$
S = - \frac{1}{4} F^2 - | \partial \phi |^2 - A_\mu J^\mu + \cdots  , \qquad J^\mu = i Q ( \phi^\dagger \partial^\mu \phi -  \partial^\mu \phi^\dagger \phi )
$$
Then, the photon 2-point function is given in perturbation theory by
\begin{align}
\langle A_\mu(x) A_\nu(0) \rangle &= \int[dA][d\phi] e^{i S} A_\mu(x) A_\nu(0) \\
&=  \int[dA][d\phi] e^{i S_{free}} \, \frac{1}{2!} \left(  \int d^4 y_1 : J^\alpha(y_1) A_\alpha(y_1) : \right)^2  A_\mu(x) A_\nu(0) \\
&=  \int d^4 y_1   d^4 y_2 D^F_{\mu\alpha}( x - y_1 ) D^F_{\nu\beta}(y_2) \langle J^\alpha(y_1) J^\beta(y_2) \rangle  \tag{1}
\end{align}
where
$$
D^F_{\mu\alpha}( x ) = \langle A_\mu(x) A_\nu(0) \rangle_{free}
$$
The diagrammatic interpretation of (1) is hopefully obvious. It shows that the $JJ$ 2-point function is related to the $AA$ 2-point function simply by an extra factor of the photon propagators.

I derived this in perturbation theory, but there is a simple generalization of this result to the full non-perturbative theory as well.

Comment: Thanks Prahar! How's it going?

Comment: I'm just trying to choose the best answer now. Do you mind saying what the simple generalization to non-perturbative theory is? Is it just Nihar Karve's answer?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you put the diagram you have shown. You have to include one or two or no propagators if it is put in a larger diagram, where more real particles are involved. Depending on which particles are real you have to include the propagators you have added to the formula $i/(q^2+i\epsilon)$.
On its own, the diagram refers to two real photons speeding in space. Then it's part of the propagator of a *single* photon. It represents a single photon traveling from one spacetime point to another. Then you have to include both propagators, obviously.

Comment: Thanks, but you didn't explain where j comes in.